# How to preserve session in Safari private window mode?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

I'm comparatively new to Mac OS.

I was a Chrome user before. In Incognito mode, it preserves the session, i.e., if you have logged in to Google and you open YouTube in the same window (but in a new tab), it automatically signs me in for that particular Gmail user in YouTube, whereas in Safari private window mode, I have to login everytime I open something new in a new tab.

I was wondering if I could make it just like Chrome by changing a few settings.

Comment: I've noticed this too, and I think it's only started to work this way in 10.10... have a feeling it used to work the way you describe in previous versions of OS X. I'm not aware of any way to change it back, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer the way that Chrome works, I would suggest using Chrome on OS X. In Incognito mode, it works the way you want.

Comment: But chrome eats a lot of battery compared to safari.